# How to use blade engine with JS-SSR in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, server-side-rendering

I would like to use Vue & Laravel. To avoid *flash of unstyled content*, I want to use SSR in Laravel using the  [Server side rendering JavaScript in your Laravel application](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-server-side-rendering) package from spatie.

However, as far as I understand it, it only works when I put the whole HTML code into a `app.vue` file and my blade only ends up to be something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My server side rendered app</title>
        <script defer src="{{ mix('app-client.js') }}">
    </head>
    <body>
        {!! ssr('js/app.vue') !!}
    </body>
</html>
```

I can't use blade syntax in `app.vue`.

Is it possible to use something like

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My server side rendered app</title>
        <script defer src="{{ mix('app-client.js') }}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            @include('layouts.nav')
            {{ __('Dear :name', ['name' => 'Adam']) }}
            @lang('Hey, welcome to this page!')
            @yield('content')
            <flash message="Hi"></flash>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

but still allow server-side rendering of Vue?

Comment: Blade runs first, then Vuejs so any templating directives understood by Blade are executed first.

Blade compiles the view, Laravel sends it to the browser then the browser executes VueJs

Comment: @JordyvD so you are saying I just can write normal blade-syntax code into the template section of `App.vue` ?

Comment: No, you can write Blade syntax in a blade file that loads app.vue. You cannot write blade syntax into files that do not end with .blade.php

Comment: @JordyvD yes, that makes sense. So if one uses SSR, one can't use blade,  because you have to put the main page content into the `app.vue` file, right?

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is an old question. But I've noticed you never really got a solid answer on this.

I've built many apps using Laravel blade and Vue single file components, in what appears to be a similar manner to what you are doing here.

In my experience, there are currently three methods here that can help you avoid FOUC or at least improve it:

1. Hide your entire #app tag contents, (using display:none or other CSS properties) and then adding a class to reveal it after Vue has finished rendering everything.
2. Use the v-cloak directive to add some CSS until the components have mounted.
3. Server side render **each component** individually and output each individually where they are placed in the DOM. I have never justified the need to do this, but it's the best overall solution as your entire page will be rendered before all the JS loads and is executed.

Hope this helps.